# Extracting a part of a Spacy document as a new document

Tags: python, nlp, document, spacy

I have a rather long text parsed by `Spacy` into a `Doc` instance:

```
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_lg')
doc = nlp(content)
```

`doc` here becomes a [`Doc` class instance](https://spacy.io/api/doc).

Now, since the text is huge, I would like to process, experiment and visualize in a Jupyter notebook using only just one part of the document - for instance, first 100 sentences.

How can I slice and create a new `Doc` instance from a part of the existing document?

Comment: The specific question is somewhat unclear. You can take a slice from `Doc` just by `Doc[index1:index2]`, the way you normally would with a python list or array. Slicing content will work normally as well, as long as content is a string. If you want to slice on sentences per se, then it becomes a bit tougher.

Comment: @Uvar sorry if it was a bit confusing. The first problem with slicing the `doc[index1:index2]` is that the result of the slice would be of a `Span` type and not the `Doc` type and the second one, as you've mentioned, is "slicing by sentence"..thank you.

Comment: Okay...I'm going to suggest a completely wacky thing here..feel free to correct it to something which makes more sense, for instance taking the sentences slice inside the comprehension instead of outside. (I did not test it extensively, so just went for I felt was safe in working):
`sentences = [sent.string.strip() for sent in doc.sents][:100]` ; `minidoc = nlp(' '.join(sentences))`

Comment: @Uvar yeah, I guess that would be one way to do it, feel free to post it as an answer. Not sure if there is a better option in Spacy. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A rather ugly way to achieve your purpose is to construct a list of sentences and build a new document from a subset of sentences.

```
sentences = [sent.string.strip() for sent in doc.sents][:100]
minidoc = nlp(' '.join(sentences))
```

It feels like there should be a better solution, but I guess this at least works.

Answer (score 8):

There's a nicer solution using `as_doc()` on a `Span` object (https://spacy.io/api/span#as_doc):

```
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_lg')
content = "This is my sentence. And here's another one."
doc = nlp(content)
for i, sent in enumerate(doc.sents):
    print(i, "a", sent, type(sent))
    doc_sent = sent.as_doc()
    print(i, "b", doc_sent, type(doc_sent))
```

Gives output:

```
0 a This is my sentence. <class 'spacy.tokens.span.Span'>   
0 b This is my sentence.  <class 'spacy.tokens.doc.Doc'>   
1 a And here's another one.  <class 'spacy.tokens.span.Span'>   
1 b And here's another one.  <class 'spacy.tokens.doc.Doc'>
```

(code snippet wrote out in full for clarity - can be further shortened ofcourse)

Answer (score 1):

My personal preference would slicing by characters. Spacy's sentence segmentation is pretty good for structured text, but for poorly structured text grabbing a bunch of text at a fixed rate (i.e. by character) is a little more predictable:

```
char_end = 200
subdoc = nlp(doc.text[:char_end])
```